# Repeating ajax every 10 milliseconds slows other ajax calls loading in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> Repeating ajax every 10 milliseconds slows other ajax calls loading in
>   the same page

I have two ajax code, one the below coded (repeating after 10 milliseconds) and one which I think not necessary to be here (it is done as per user input)

```
var checkState = function() {
  var url = "http://domain.in/quiz/quiz_inplay_time_difference.php?record=30";
  $.ajax({
    url: url
  }).done(function(data) {
    var time_left_display = $('#time_left_display');
    //initialize the time
    var time_left = String(data.time_left);
    var hyphen = '';
    if (time_left.indexOf("-") !== -1) {
      hyphen = '-';
    }
    if (time_left <= -1) {
      window.location.replace("http://domain.in/quiz/quiz_result.php?record=30");
    }

    if (time_left <= 60) {
      $('#time_bar').removeClass("alert-info");
      $('#time_bar').addClass("alert-warning");
    }
    if (time_left <= 10) {
      $('#time_bar').removeClass("alert-warning");
      $('#time_bar').addClass("alert-danger");
    }

    time_left = time_left.replace('-', '');
    var minutes = Math.floor(time_left / 60);
    var seconds = time_left % 60;
    //update the time
    time_left_display.html(hyphen + minutes.toString() + ':' + seconds.toString());

  });

}

checkState();
setInterval(checkState, 10);
```

When I load the page at the local server (wampserver), the above code and other ajax calls works fast and gives result as expected. But the same page when I load on the server (domain.in) the other ajax (which is called as per user's input) works very very slow.

So, to check where's the issue, I removed `setInterval(checkState, 10);` from the code and ran on the server (domain.in) the other ajax (which is called as per user's input) works fast as expected.

My Question:

> Is my above code correct? Can it be more easy, and quick to run? Any
>   other alternatives for it?

Comment: Ajax calls run asynchronous to the page not to each other that is to say that Ajax queries are stacked in a queue of sorts, what you are looking for is parallel execution of Ajax . jQuery deferred functions can help you do that , see ref: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Deferred

Comment: On your local server it's theoretically possible for you to get a response back in 10ms, on a real server there is almost no way that will happen ever.  So all your ajax requests are piling up (you are doing ~100 per second, and they might take half a second or a second to complete).  Choose a more reasonable timeout value, 500ms?  1000?